# Ticks ploted twice

Tags: python

I made the following code to plot a series but it does show certain tick twice dunno why.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title('Company', fontdict={'fontsize': 40, 'fontweight': 'medium'})
ax1 = sns.lineplot(data=DF,x="Dates" ,y="Price",label="Blabla")
ax1.set(yscale='log')
ax1.set_yticks(TICKARRAY)
ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

Below Is the output I have, how do I hide red circle values (60 & 40) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this discussion on Github: [Setting axis ticks in log scale produces duplicate tick labels](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11575/). Here, someone suggested:

> For some (maybe desired?) reason, minor ticks are labelled as well, depending on the axis bounds. A workaround is to turn them off.

Thus, you can try to solve by adding the following lines of code:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, NullFormatter
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
    axis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
```